# NFC in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

any body know about nfc in iPhone... ?

it is new feature of iphone..

Comment: It is not. The iPhone does currently not support NFC

Answer (score 1):

Quick Googling shows that NFC might be in the next iPhone. In current iPhone generations you have to rely on external hardware.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering, NFC is an emerging technology that allows your cellphone to act as a credit card, and make retail payments.

The NFC mobile-payment application went on trials in the United States, Germany, Finland, and a few other countries starting in 2007.  The Nokia 6131 was the first fully integrated mobile-payment cell phone. A primary use is buying commuter tickets.

You swipe your phone near an NFC reader, and it works like a credit card. An NFC phone is associated with a credit-card company just like it's associated with a phone-service provider.

The technology is similar to the RFID (radio frequency identification), except NFC chips allow for two-way communication instead of only one way, which allows it to work, even if you can't make a call (e.g. you are in a subway station).  NFC stands for "Near Field Communication".

Peter

Comment: You are referring to the card emulation mode defined by NFC Forum. Keep in mind NFC is more than that. Simple Tag reading/writign and P2P communication is included, too

Answer (score 0):

They've made an NFC adapter for iPhone: http://www.icarte.ca.